# Regarding black holes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, biophysics, estimation, hawking-radiation

If I could create a mini-black hole, yeah I know, it would evaporate away in a fraction of a nano-second, but would the energy emitted by the Hawking radiation kill me?
Or would it produce only a tiny amount of energy?

Answer (score 2):

The time for Hawking radiation evaporation of a black hole is
$$
T_{ev}~=~8.41\times 10^{-17}\left(\frac{M}{1kg}\right)^3s,
$$
so that in the last second of quantum evaporation the mass of the black hole is
$$
M~=~\left(\frac{1}{8.41\times 10^{-17}}\right)^{1/3}kg~=~2.3\times 10^5kg.
$$
The core of nuclear bomb involve on the order of $100kg$ of nuclear material, and less than $1\%$ of it is converted to energy. This means in the last second a mini-black hole will produce as much energy of $10^5$ to $10^6$ nuclear bombs. You would not want to be close to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look:   http://xaonon.dyndns.org/hawking/

If you created a black hole out of colliding 2 protons using the CERN collider (which so far, they've not been able to do, or at least, they haven't observed that outcome), such a black hole probably wouldn't kill you if you were near it.  It would shoot out a bunch of high energy particles, some of them anti-matter, but not enough to kill you.   You probably wouldn't even feel it, but you might see it, if one passed through your brain or eye.  I've heard that astronauts saw cosmic rays in space.   But, getting hit by a few very fast moving particles is pretty harmless.   Too many probably isn't a good idea but a small enough black hole, the mass of a few large atoms - mostly harmless.

If you create a black hole out of a weight big enough for you to see, like a grain of sand, and you apply E=MC^2 to that grain of sand, that would probably kill you.    It all depends on the mass of the blackhole.  Enough mass and the explosion gets very very large.   A grain of sand mass black hole would evaporate, in a tiny fraction of a nanosecond, and that would have enough energy (perhaps) to level a city block.   (If somebody wants to improve my estimate, feel free), but a leveled city block from just a grain of sand of energy seems about right to me.

If you make it large enough that the evaporation stops being a problem but the mass of the black hole becomes a problem, where you'd need billions or trillions of tons to have it cool enough to not vaporize you if you were in the same room, but . . . then there's the problem of a trillion ton object the size of a speck too small to see and that could cause problems in a different way, by gravitationally pulling you into it for example, if you got too close.  It would also fall right through the Earth and out the other side and it would leave a path of destruction everywhere it went.

That's why they say "It's all fun and games until somebody makes a black hole."